# MySQL vote history for user with total vote count for each item

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have tables similar to these:

```
names (these are being voted on)
+----+-------+
| ID | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name3 |
|  4 | name4 | 
+----+-------+

votes
+----+----------+------+---------+
| ID | voter_id | time | name_id |
+----+----------+------+---------+
|  1 |     1    |   x  |    1    |
|  2 |     2    |   x  |    1    |
|  3 |     3    |   x  |    2    |
|  4 |     4    |   x  |    2    |
|  5 |     5    |   x  |    4    |
+----+----------+------+---------+

expected result for voter_id 1
| n.ID | n.name | v.time | votecount|
+------+--------+--------+----------+
|   1  |  name1 |   x    |      2   |
+------+--------+--------+----------+
```

The query I'm using:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.VOTE_ID) VOTECOUNT, v.VOTE_TIME, v.VOTER_ID, n.ID, n.NAME
FROM `votes` as v
LEFT JOIN `names` as n
ON n.ID = v.NAME_ID
WHERE v.VOTER_ID = :id
GROUP BY n.ID
ORDER BY v.TIME DESC
```

Alternate query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.VOTE_ID) VOTECOUNT, v.VOTE_TIME, v.VOTER_ID, n.ID, n.NAME
FROM `votes` as v
LEFT JOIN `names` as n
ON n.ID = v.NAME_ID
GROUP BY n.ID
HAVING v.VOTER_ID = :id
ORDER BY v.TIME DESC
```

I'm trying to get a list of items that user has voted for and also count how many votes in total each item has gotten.

If I use the WHERE clause the votecount is obviously always 1, but it gets all items the user has voted for.
I've tried using HAVING voter_id to keep the votecount total and that sort of works, but then some items the user has voted on are omitted for some reason. Changing LEFT JOIN for RIGHT JOIN would give a slightly different list, but never complete.
Would there be some better way of doing this?

Comment: You stated you need to, "Get a list of items that a user has voted for and also count how many votes in total each item has gotten".... What column denotes an item? the name_ID?  If so what happens if you add that to the group by in your first query?  mysql extensions of the group by statement may be hiding your problem.  Also ***provide expected results for your data examples provided*** to help clarify your desire.

Comment: next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, try replacing your `HAVING` clause in the second query with `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN v.VOTER_ID = :id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`.

Second, your select list doesn't match up with your group by, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.  What is the time column exactly?  My attempt at what you want would look something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.VOTE_ID) VOTECOUNT, n.ID, n.NAME
FROM `votes` as v
LEFT JOIN `names` as n
ON n.ID = v.NAME_ID
GROUP BY n.ID, n.NAME
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN v.VOTER_ID = :id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: Time would be the timestamp for the vote. I'm not sure whats wrong with the group by, but I suppose I was selecting columns I really didn't need. That HAVING clause appears to make it work perfectly without having to change anything else. Thanks for that, would've never figured that out on my own!